# Split CSV files into exact 1gb files or little less?

Tags: c#, csv, split, size, limit

Every month we receive a invoice file that is always bigger then 2GB, our print house has a 1.1GB limitation and we currently do all these process by hand.

The first step in this application would be to be able to split those HUGE 2GB files into limited 1GB files in a way it won't break each CSV entry and that each files will be readable from the start to the end without breaking any data.

How could I split the file to me the above requirements ?

Are there any libraries for this such of process on CSV files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just copying the first 1 GB of data from the source into a new file, then searching backward for the last newline, and truncating the new file after that.  Then you know how large the first file is, and you repeat the process for a second new file from that point to 1 GB later.  Seems straightforward to me in just about any language (you mentioned C#, which I haven't used recently, but certainly it can easily do the job).

You didn't make it clear whether you need to copy the header line (if any) to each of the resulting files.  Again, should be straightforward--just do it prior to the copying of data into each of the files.

You could also take the approach of just generically splitting the files using `tar` on Unix or some Zip-like utility on Windows, then telling your large-file-challenged partner to reconstruct the file from that format.  Or maybe simply compressing the CSV file would work, and get you under the limit in practice.

Comment: That won't work. You need to compensate for quoting, in a number of different forms (single vs double)

Comment: @Stephan: I doubt it.  Most CSV files are not fully general, and naive processing works fine in practice.  Do you really think the cells in the CSV here contain newlines?  Or is there some other pitfall you have in mind?

Comment: @John each entry is separated by a `;` and at the end a newline. Won't it be a lot mroe process that way ? for example I would split the last 1GB then i would check wether the last line was good or not, then i would have to split the next file and correct the first line and also check wether it was missing too and also would have to count the lines to know where I should start the next split... Inst there a better approach

Comment: Naive processing does not work at all if you cannot control the source. Fields in csv files contain newlines and single and double quotes. Field separators and record separators are not well-defined, the document encoding is undefined.

Comment: @Prix: you have identified probably most of the issues you need to handle, so writing the code should be straightforward now.  Is there an "easier" way?  Depends on your definition of easy.  Do you feel like instantiating an ODBC module and using it to load your CSV file and copying rows into an ODBC object, or something like that?  Seems like gigantic overkill to me, but maybe it would address Stephan's concern about newlines within cells in your CSV (which I wholeheartedly feel is over-engineering here).

Comment: That depends on the day of the week the import breaks. On mondays its ok, but if they are processed on fridays... This is an ideal problem to learn test-driven development, b.t.w.

Answer (score 1):

There are just a few things you need to take care of:

- Keep the line breaks: split the file on a new line (algorithmically said split the file on the previous line to that where the 1GB limit occured minus the header line size)
- Copy the header to the beginning of the new file and then paste the rest
- Preserve the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

In a bash/terminal prompt, write:

```
man split
```

.. then

```
man wc
```

.. simply count the number of lines in the file, divide it by X, feed the number to split and you have X files less than 1.1GB (if x = filesize/1.1)

Comment: I think you could do it using `split --line-bytes 1000m`.  Not sure, haven't tried it, but it seems likely to work and trivial to test.

Comment: sorry but it is a C# solution and as such would like it to be dealt in C# ofc.

Comment: @Prix fair enough. The C# tag wasn't there 6 hours ago, was it? anyway ..

Comment: yes it was there since the creation of the question and nothing has been changed on the question since then.

Comment: My suggestion can be applied directly in C#, provided you only have newlines at the end of each line. The calculation can be used to jump down through the file in one big chunk, but there is another way. Just go one good line at the time, calculating the amount of bytes this line would add to the grand total if added. Start a new file if you get over the limit, dump the line to the current file if not. It's a linear line by line run through, which probably takes a good deal of time. If the lines take up more or less the same amount of bytes, you can speed up the process.